# C++ MSVC - Show uncaught exception message

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, compilation

I have a simple C++ code that I try to compile with Visual Studio 2019:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    throw std::runtime_error{ "TEST" };
    return 0;
}
```

Running this program in `PowerShell` results only in displaying "Hello world". From my experience using GCC I would expect to see message containing `TEST` somewhere in terminal output, like:

```
Hello World!                                                                                                                                    
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'                                                                             
  what():  TEST                                                                                                                                 
Aborted
```

These are the compiler flags used:

```
/permissive- /GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"Release\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /std:c++17 /FC /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\ThrowTest.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

How to compile this program on Windows, using MSVC, to show what exception was thrown when running it?

Comment: I think it is not an issue of compiling or linkage, but more where `stderr` is redirected to using powershell or what the returned error code by invoking your program is like..

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/abort?view=vs-2019

Comment: I do not know about GCC, but why VC would display `TEST`? Are you looking for the Debug Configuration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual C++ Exception not shown in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588305/visual-c-exception-not-shown-in-console)

Answer (score 0):

How to compile this program on Windows, using MSVC, to show what exception was thrown when running it?

If you want to see the message after you are able to compile, you need try catch blocks, and you need to catch the exception:

```
int runTimeError(){
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    try{
        throw std::runtime_error( "TEST" );
    }catch (std::exception& ex){
        std::cout << ex.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `To be able to compile using MSVC you need to change the {} to (), or curly to round brackets` this is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are asking is possible, but I would like to be proven wrong. GCC beats MSVC in this regard.  The only way I know of to find out what caused an exception is to use the Visual Studio IDE. From there I "Start Debugging" and the "Exception Unhandled" pop-up will show me the exception type. From the "Call Stack" window I can also find out which line caused the exception.

But since you mention `PowerShell`, it may be that you are compiling and running from the command line. If so, you can at least be notified that **some exception** happened by using one of the [CRT debug libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-debugging-techniques?view=msvc-170), so your complete command line could be e.g:

`cl /MTd /EHsc file.cpp`

Running `file.exe` would (with your example code) pop-up the same "Debug Error!" MessageBox that you get in Visual Studio when you "Start Without Debugging".